# Print/collate each element in each array in a 2 dimensional array

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a 2 dimensional array, with some values in them, eg:

```
[[11, 12, 13],[21, 22, 23],[31, 32, 33]]
```

How would I print these values so the output would become:

```
11 21 31
12 22 32
13 23 33
```

(add in the spaces later, I'm assuming)

Comment: ```zip``` should help - take a look in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like said in the comments, you can do this with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) -

```
>>> lst = [[11, 12, 13],[21, 22, 23],[31, 32, 33]]
>>> print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, s)) for s in zip(*lst)))
11 21 31
12 22 32
13 23 33
```